# Origin of the word Refactoring

Tags: refactoring

Code refactoring is the process of changing a computer program's internal structure without modifying its external behavior or existing functionality.

What is the origin of the word refactoring and why was it chosen to denote the above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: this is [asked on english language learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150312/whatss-the-root-word-of-refactoring?newreg=9649fc7abc7e4bdf8b48eca5f30c8d6a), even though it is relevent to computer programming it is better suited there.

Answer (score 20):

Factor has its origins in latin, the root means [make or maker](http://www.latin-dictionary.org/JM-Latin-English-Dictionary/factor) (hence factory, manufacture, etc). The mathematical sense of factor could possibly be interpreted as "how is this number made".

So to re-factor simply means to re-make

Answer (score 14):

In [Refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactoring#History), Fowler wrote that he hasn't *"succeded in pinning down the
   real birth of the term    Refactoring"*. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactoring#History) mentions the term was used by Forth programmers in the 80s, Fowler also spoke about the Smalltalk community.

Math factorization's certainly helped coining this term as you don't change the value of a mathematical expression what you factorize it.

Comment: See https://martinfowler.com/bliki/EtymologyOfRefactoring.html

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics, to factor (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) is to reduce an expression to it's simplest form. Surely the same applies here?

Comment: Refactoring software is more of a transformation than a simplification though?

Comment: But what is the purpose of that transformation? I would argue to make existing code:
1) more readable
2) more efficient.

And in my opinion, efficient code is usually simpler cleaner code.

Comment: Most refactoring are reversable (extract method - inline method) and you might want to make temporarily a method bigger to be able to apply  another refactoring at a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

Martin Fowler wrote about the [Etymology of Refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EtymologyOfRefactoring.html). Quoting:

> The foundations of what we refer to these days as refactoring comes from the Smalltalk communities. However the metaphor of factoring a program was also part of the Forth community. [Bill Wake dug out](http://laputan.org/catfish/2011/03/post.html) the first known printed mention of the word "refactoring" in a Thinking Forth, a 1984 book by Leo Brodie. We're pretty sure that this usage didn't pass from the Forth community to the Smalltalk community, but developed independently.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Brian Foote](http://laputan.org/catfish/2011/03/post.html), the first use of the technical word "refactoring" in print appeared in the book "Thinking Forth" in 1984.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably, in context of software it was coined by Martin Fowler http://www.refactoring.com/

Comment: Negative. Even Wikipedia shows the term was used in this context before 1990.

Comment: We were refactoring code long before Fowler, and the term was in use long before Fowler's book as well.

Comment: Still, without Fowler, even this thread would most probably not exist...The credit should be acknowledged.